# visibility: visible not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
<style>

    #checkboxDIV {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #itemcard:hover #checkboxDIV {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #options {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #itemcard:hover #options {
        visibility: visible;
    }

</style>
```

When I move my mouse on `#itemcard` , It works for #options and shows `#options` DIV,

But it is not working `#checkboxDIV` - I am not sure what is causing it, Please see the HTML code at the bottom

any idea?

**EDIT:** Adding HTML for better understanding

```
@foreach (var I in Model)
{
    <tr id="row_@I._id">
        <td class="v-align-top" >
            <div class="checkbox text-center" id="checkboxDIV">
                <input type="checkbox" value="@I._id" id="checkbox_@I._id)">
                <label for="checkbox_@I._id"></label>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard">
             <div id="options">OPTIONS<div>
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML as well.

Comment: Added HTML code

Comment: you cannot have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: @GarrGodfrey i dont understand - I dont have multiple items with same ID

Comment: if you have multiple rows, each row will have an #itemcard. But the problem is that checkboxDIV is not a descendant of itemcard

Comment: Also multiple elements with `id="checkboxDIV"` and `id="options"`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey oh yes, you are right. How can I tackle this problem, because i want to trigger it when mouse is moved on `#itemcard`

Comment: there's no previous sibling or parent selector in css. you'd need to rearrange your dom or use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this

```
 <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard" >
```

```css
#checkboxDIV {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #itemcard:hover #checkboxDIV {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #options {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #itemcard2:hover #options {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="">
        <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard" >
            <div class="checkbox text-center" id="checkboxDIV">
                <input type="checkbox" value="@I._id" id="checkbox_@I._id)">
                <label for="checkbox_@I._id"></label>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard2">
             <div id="options">OPTIONS<div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```